# Git Publisher "target remote name" validation problems, single repo

Tags: git, jenkins, tags, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to use the Git Publisher plugin to tag a successful build with the $BUILD_TAG, but I cannot figure out a value for the *Target remote name* that it will accept. If I use the *Repository URL* in the GIT configuration I'm told, **No remote repository configured with the name** . I tried naming the configuration and using that as the *Target remote name*, no luck.

My SCM configuration (company name elided):

- **Repository URL**: http://stash.company.com/scm/semsrch/medqp.git
- **Credentials**: sebuserro/******  [This is configured by our build team]
- **Name**: experiment
- **Branch Specifier**: origin/experiment

My Git Publisher configuration:

- **Push Only If Build Succeeds**: checked
- **Tag to push**: $BUILD_TAG
- **Tag message**: $BUILD_URL
- **Create new tag**: checked
- **Target remote name**: http://stash.company.com/scm/semsrch/medqp.git

There is something about Git that I'm missing here.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: FYI there is one confusing thing - if you just edited git config without saving job configuration, the publisher plug-in may show that remote with such name does not exist while it has just been configured in. (I mean accepted answer is correct, just adding how I've been confused)

Answer (score 65):

If your branch name is experiment and remote name is origin, change your SCM and Git Publisher configuration to:

SCM configuration:

- Name: "origin"
- Branch Specifier: "*/experiment"

Git Publisher configuration:

- Target remote name: "origin"

The important thing, is to set the same name for Name parameter in SCM and Target remote name in Git Publisher.

I know it's a bit too late for answer, but maybe someone will find it useful.

Comment: Thank's for this.. On line documentation is very poor

Comment: Better documentation that you'll find anywhere, thank you.

Answer (score 15):

Target remote name: will be  "origin"

You can execute shell and generate custom tag and pass the same to git publisher.

Comment: That won't work if you're using `Multiple SCMs` option, only a solitary `Git` option.